# Calling dynamic .Include list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

i am working on an asp.net mvc web application. and i have the following repository method,, where i will be passing the .Include() dynamically :-

```
   public async Task<SecurityRole> FindSecurityRole(int id,string path="")
              {
                  return await context.SecurityRoles.Include(path).SingleOrDefaultAsync(a2 => a2.SecurityRoleID == id);
}
```

now inside my controller i want to call the above method as follow:-

```
await uniteofwork.SecurityRoleRepository.FindSecurityRole(id.Value,)
```

but i am not sure what are the apporachies i can follow to pass the properties ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can chain calls to things like `Include` over multiple lines by storing the result in a variable. Nothing will actually hit your database until you call an evaluating expression like `SingleOrDefaultAsync` here.

```
var query = context.SecurityRoles;
foreach (var include in path.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    query = query.Include(include);
}

return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a2 => a2.SecurityRoleID == id);
```

Splitting the string allows you to pass multiple include hierarchies at once, comma-delimited.

Comment: thanks , and how i will be calling the above method ,, should i pass it inside a string "NavigationProperty1,NavigationProperty2" ? for example "repository.Call(1,"NP1,NP"");"

Comment: Yes,  exactly. Include takes either a string or lambda expressions.

Comment: but how i can pass lamdba expression in my case ? because it will allow me to prevent hard coding the navigation properties.. but i am not sure how i can pass the navigation properties as lambada expression..

Comment: you code did not work in my case,, so i did the following modifications:-  var query = context.SecurityRoles.AsQueryable();
                  foreach (var include in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                  {
                      query = query.Include(include);
                  }